# Is there any way to enable microsoft silverlight in IOS?

Tags: ios

Some websites need Microsoft silverlight for streaming. Is it possible  or is there any way to enable Microsoft Silverlight on IOS devices?

Answer (score 3):

No. [Silverlight is not supported on iOS devices.](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/what-is-silverlight/#sys-req)

Answer (score 1):

There is a back to front way. Use the horizon app to log into vmware server to load a version of windows running ie with silver light. Not fast but it works in a pinch.